# Using LaTeX commands inside pgfplotsset

Tags: pgfplots, pgfkeys

Is there any way to use LaTeX commands inside `\pgfplotsset`?

For instance, the following code produces an error indicated in the `\pgfplotsset` line, whereas if one replaced `\contents` in the `\pgfplotsset` command with `axis x line=bottom` then all would be well.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcommand{\contents}{axis x line=bottom}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{\contents}  % <----- fails with ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgfplots/axis x line=bottom'

\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain=-3e-3:3e-3,samples=201]{exp(-x^2 / (2e-3^2)) / (1e-3 * sqrt(2*pi))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at [Settting PGFplots axis environment options by means of \newcommand and {\newlength,\setlength}](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145633)

Comment: @Johannes_B: good point generally, thanks.  The reason I want to do this is to address a problem raised in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195029/how-can-i-escape-the-scope-of-an-environment which I don't think I can solve easily by using styles, but I'll look into it further.

Comment: it needs to be expanded so it is `\expandafter\pgfplotsset\expandafter{\contents}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably Till Tantau was having similar problems so he created the error messages in a smarter way. Example; if I go something like this

```
\tikz[xasfwr=yeah]{}
```

The error message is

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key `/tikz/xasfwr`, to which you passed `yeah`, and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Now your example; let's read the error message

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key `/pgfplots/axis x line=bottom`

Notice that  it doesn't say you tried to pass `bottom` it says that it didn't understand the whole thing. Because it didn't parse it and missed the equation sign and the value you have provided. You can get more stupid cases such as

```
\pgfplotsset{\contents=out haha so funny}
```

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key `/pgfplots/axis x line=bottom`, to which you passed `out haha so funny`, and I am going to ignore it.

These all tell that PGF keys didn't expand it properly. One immediate thing is to manually expand the argument by delaying the expandion of `\pgfplotsset{` part

```
\expandafter\pgfplotsset\expandafter{\contents}
```

would work. Or you can still stay within PGF keys and use the `/.expanded` handler which does the expansion for you.

```
\pgfkeys{/utils/exec/.expanded={\noexpand\pgfplotsset{\contents}}}
```

What does this do? First, `/utils/exec` is the general handler for executing arbitrary TeX code. Then by just identifying what should not be expanded, here `\pgfplotsset` and adding `\noexpand` before them, you can set any kind of macro values.

You can also control how many times it should expand and you can check the manual for `expand once` and `expand twice` keys for that.

Answer (score 6):

You did mention in a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195029/how-can-i-escape-the-scope-of-an-environment#comment451103_195029) that you are writing a small lua Script to output the `\pgfplotsset` command. Writing a simple texfile is easy, which can be read after the environment (here called `foobar`) closes.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-pgf.tex}
\pgfplotsset{width=5cm}
% I am the file your Lua script makes
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newenvironment{foobar}{}{}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AfterEndEnvironment{foobar}{\input{\jobname-pgf}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot{x+1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{foobar}
    %Some luacode wrting a file represented by filecontents
\end{foobar}
%this file is being read here ^
%pgfplotsset is executed
\begin{axis}
\addplot{x^2};
\end{axis}
% the whole set is limited to the scope of the tikzpicture
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
\addplot{-x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%everything back to normal herea
\end{document}
```

You should define your definitions as styles and later reuse
them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{contents/.style={axis x line=bottom}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain=-3e-3:3e-3,samples=201]{exp(-x^2 / (2e-3^2)) / (1e-3 * sqrt(2*pi))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\pgfplotsset{contents}%JB: That would change the behaviour
%globally

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[contents]%JB: Just for this axis environment
\addplot[domain=-3e-3:3e-3,samples=201]{exp(-x^2 / (2e-3^2)) / (1e-3 * sqrt(2*pi))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Johannes_B, but see my comment on the question itself.

Comment: @JPi Just figuring out the problem.

Comment: @JPi I have added a completely different approach.

Comment: Thinking about it this is more or less another approach to your other question, but does not help here in any way.